# Android ActivityGroup lifecycle deprecated?

Tags: android, android-activity, activitygroup, activity-lifecycle

So from a few days I've seen warning in my whole application about `super.onPause()`, `super.onDestroy()`, `super.onResume()`  and etc. has been deprecated. I want to ask is if that means that in the future these methods will not be invoke as they were working before..and which is the new ways to control and invoke the specific things which I want to use or initialize in these methods. Fragments?

Comment: ActivityGroup has been decprecated

Comment: none of those methods have been deprecated,your Activity group has.You should look about Fragments instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the docs on [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html). Here's a relevant quote (which you seem to have read, but future readers might not):

> This class is deprecated. Use the new Fragment and FragmentManager
>   APIs instead; these are also available on older platforms through the
>   Android compatibility package.

If I were you I'd replace the use of `ActivityGroup` if possible (i.e. assume they'll stop working as expected).

Comment: Thanks anyway, I didn't realize that it was my ActivityGroup implementation not Activity : )